# Gnome keeps asking to install extension on login

Tags: gnome, gnome-tweak-tool

This has been a problem for very long time that I haven't gotten around to fixing. I once installed this extension called [Only Blank with Closed Lid - Switch](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/417/blank-on-lid/). It never worked and I wanted to get rid of it, so I removed it from my installed applications in http://extensions.gnome.org/. Ever since then it ALWAYS asks to install it when I log in: [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpbqk.jpg)

I've tried re-installing and uninstalling it, deleting the folder in `./local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`, uninstalling from the gnome-tweaks gui.

I also ran the command `gsettings set org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions ...` and removed it from the list, which didn't work.

I don't really want to reset my gnome configuration for a small issue like this, any suggestions?

Comment: what happens if you rename your entire .local folder ( as an experiment.. you can always rename it back ) `mv .local .local~` then log out and back in... does that change anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A great way to start troubleshooting something like this is to search your home folder for text files that might refer to this extension:

something like

```
grep -rnwH '~/' -e 'blank'
```

And then you will be able to figure out what's looking for that extention.

More info on searching for text in files here: [How do I find all files containing specific text on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/how-do-i-find-all-files-containing-specific-text-on-linux)

If you can't find a script in your home folder, look for a culparte in `/etc/profile.d/`

Comment: found it in `.local/share/gnome-software/install-queue` and I deleted it. Finally!